# Is there a way to set specific leave and arrive points in OR-Tools routing?

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm working with optimizing the routes taken by a CNC machine being fed with G-Code files. When the machine is drilling holes the solution is straightforward. But what if I want to optimize the drawing of text and shapes where there is a static route that must be followed?

For example, consider I am trying to draw the word "TAX". The G-Code that draws this looks like this:

```
(TAX)
(T)
N10 G0 Z2
N20 G0 X0 Y30
N30 G1 Z-1
N40 G1 X16.667 Y30
N50 G0 Z2
N60 G0 X8.333 Y30
N70 G1 Z-1
N80 G1 X8.333 Y0
(A)
N90 G0 Z2
N100 G0 X26.667 Y0
N110 G1 Z-1
N120 G1 X36.667 Y30
N130 G1 X46.667 Y0
N140 G0 Z2
N150 G0 X43.888 Y8.333
N160 G1 Z-1
N170 G1 X29.445 Y8.333
(X)
N180 G0 Z2
N190 G0 X56.667 Y0
N200 G1 Z-1
N210 G1 X76.667 Y30
N220 G0 Z2
N230 G0 X56.667 Y30
N240 G1 Z-1
N250 G1 X76.667 Y0
```

In this example we can go FROM any of these points:

```
X16.667 Y30
X8.333 Y0
X46.667 Y0
X29.445 Y8.333
X76.667 Y30
X76.667 Y0
```

...TO any of these points:

```
X16.667 Y30
X8.333 Y0
X46.667 Y0
X29.445 Y8.333
X76.667 Y30
X76.667 Y0
```

...in any order.

I've been reading over the documentation and examples for [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp#circuit_board) but I don't see any options that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

RoutingIndexManager has an overload with start/end point. does it solve your issue?

```
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data.locations), data.num_vehicles, data.starts, data.ends)
```

Comment: No. Some points may route to any point while other points must route to a specific point. For now I'm manually enforcing 0 between points that must route to one another in the distance matrix but it's kind of an ugly hack and I expect it to break.